# How can I solved the returning function in python program?

Tags: while-loop, return

I write a program with min, max function with two loop.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
            list=[]
            while True:
                x = (input("Enter a number: "))
                list.append(int(x))
                largest = max(list)
                smallest = min(list)
    except:
            list = x
            if list == 'done':
                break
            else:
                print("[!!] Invalid input, please start again the list!")
                continue

print("The smallest value is: ", smallest)
print("The largest value is: ", largest)
```

Thank you.

It is pretty good. But the problem is if I type wrong, not integer character, I must to restart the integer input from the beginning.

It would be prettier, if I would get an error message, e.g.:

```
Please give me integer number
```

instead of

```
[!!] Invalid input, please start again the list!
```

and I can continue to  fill the started list.

Answer (score 0):

While receiving your input you can check your inputs type

```
while True:
            x = (input("Enter a number: "))
            if (isinstance(x, int)):
                list.append(int(x))
                largest = max(list)
                smallest = min(list)
            else:
                print("Please give me integer number")
                list=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
def loop(list):

    smallest=min(list)
    largest=max(list)
    return(smallest, largest)

list=[]

while True:

    num = (input("Enter a number: "))
    if num == "q":
        break
    try:
            num = int(num)
            list.append(num)
    except:
            print("[!!] Invalid input, please start again the list!")

smallest, largest = loop(list)

print("The smallest value is: ", smallest)

print("The largest value is: ", largest)
```